# Running sbt as headless server

Tags: scala, sbt, headless

fsc runs a headless server that compiles Scala code without loading the Scala compiler to memory each time. As a Vim user I find this very convenient, since I like to use keymaps to compile and run programs with shell commands.

sbt is a build system that provides you with more advanced options(like dependency management), but if you don't want to wait for it to load every single time, you have to run it in interactive shell mode - which means I can't control it from Vim.

I want to enjoy both worlds - run sbt as a headless server and interact with it using a lightweight shell tool.

Is it possible? I don't necessarily need to run sbt or a fork of it directly - a wrapper will also work. I couldn't find such wrapper, so if there is no solution I might have to pick up the glove and write one myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution for what you are looking for would be VimSIDE:

- https://github.com/vim-scripts/vimside

There is too a quickfix sbt plugin which partially improve the situation:

- https://github.com/dscleaver/sbt-quickfix

Comment: VimSIDE does not support sbt, and the readme doesn't say anything about dependency management, which is a big requirement.

Comment: Anyways, the VimShell plugin that VimSIDE might be a good temporary solution, so I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: For vimside, it's a good idea to monitor https://github.com/megaannum/vimside too, which might contain more frequent updates.